# Plotting with arrowheads and labels

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeling

I want to add arrowheads and labels to the following plot.

```
P1 = Plot[x, {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Red}, Filling -> Bottom];
P2 = Plot[6 x, {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Blue}];
 Show[P1, P2, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRangePadding -> None, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Axes -> None, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black],  
 LabelStyle -> {18, Bold}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{None, "T"}, {"w", None} }, ImageSize -> 500]
```

I want the arrowheads towards the origin and the label (say, "w=T") to be on the curve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Draw with graphics primitives using `Epilog`

```
P1 = Plot[x, {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Red}, Filling -> Bottom];
P2 = Plot[6 x, {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Blue}];
Show[P1, P2, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRangePadding -> None, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Axes -> None, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black], LabelStyle -> {18, Bold}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{None, "T"}, {"w", None}}, ImageSize -> 500, 
 Epilog -> {
   Arrow[{{.2, .2}, {.1, .1}}],
   Arrow[{.05 {1, 6}, {1, 6} .02}], 
   Rotate[Text[Style["w=t", FontSize -> 20], {.95, 1.1}], Pi/4]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! How can I put arrows labeling the axes (I mean "---- w ----->")?
Actually the axes labeling looks a bit odd. Want to modify them..

Comment: Also how to get rid of that double (0,0) at the origin?

Comment: putting graphics outside the plot axes is actually quite a pain. You can theoretically use graphcs as your `FrameLabels`, but getting them sized right is a chore.  You can of course use the gui drawing tools..  Personally I take it to powerpoint at that stage.

Comment: to get rid of the zero you need to use `FrameTicks`, manually specify the ticks you *do* want.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to `Epilog`you can use the `PlotStyle` settings to add arrows:

```
Plot[{x, 6 x}, {x, 0, 2}, Filling -> {1 -> Bottom}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 2}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black], LabelStyle -> {18, Bold}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{None, "T"}, {"w", None}}, ImageSize -> 400, 
 PlotStyle -> {({Arrowheads[{{-.05, 0.}, {.5, 1/2, 
                 Graphics[Text[Style["w = T\n", Large, Bold, Italic, Black]]]}}], 
                 Red, Dashed, Arrow @@ #} &), 
               ({Arrowheads[{{-.05, 0.}}], Blue, Dashed, Arrow @@ #} &)}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively, you can provide the `Arrowheads` specs as part of `PlotStyle` and post-process the `Plot` output to replace `Line`s with `Arrow`s to get the same picture.

```
Plot[{x, 6 x}, {x, 0, 2}, Filling -> {1 -> Bottom}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 2}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black], LabelStyle -> {18, Bold}, 
  FrameLabel -> {{None, "T"}, {"w", None}}, ImageSize -> 400, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Arrowheads[{{-.05, 0.}, {.5, 1/2, 
        Graphics[Text[Style["w = T\n", Large, Bold, Italic, Black]]]}}], Red, Dashed}, 
                {Arrowheads[{{-.05, 0.}}], Blue, Dashed}}] /. Line -> Arrow
```